# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in /home2/cgobr/public_html/wp-content/themes/coin/page-home.php on line 17

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

Let me begin by saying that I know pretty much nothing about PHP, and was just attempting to swap image sliders on my homepage as one was conflicting with a required plugin. I'm getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in /home2/cgobr/public_html/wp-content/themes/coin/page-home.php on line 17

Can somebody please tell me where the coding is wrong. I mean, I'm not retarded, I know css, I know html, just not php stuff. Please please please help!!! Below is the code:

```
<?php
/**
* Template name: Home
*/
?>

<?php get_header() ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
});
</script>
<div id="home_top">
<div id="home_rare"><ul><?=do_shortcode("[home_rare]") ?></ul></div>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[soliloquy id="79129"]"); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<center>
<object width="980" height="30">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.monex.com/tickers/ticker_980.swf" />
<embed src="http://www.monex.com/tickers/ticker_980.swf" width="980" height="30">
</embed></object>
<br><Br><a href="http://stores.ebay.com/coingalleryofbocaraton" target="_blank"><img src="http://cgobr.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/EbayStoreBanner1.jpg"></a></center><br>
<div id="home_content">
<div id="home_content_left">
<?php the_post() ?>
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content() ?>
<?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'kameleon' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>
<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'kameleon' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ) ?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="home_content_right">
<h2 class="entry-title">Featured Video</h2>
<iframe width="300" height="169" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YQ2UIEZMCAE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<br><br>
<h2 class="entry-title">Like Us on Facebook</h2>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCoinGalleryofSouthFlorida&amp;width=292&amp;height=500&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=true&amp;appId=277341438944784" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:500px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<?=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_video', true)?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php
global $woocommerce;

$query_args = array('posts_per_page' => $number, 'no_found_rows' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product' );

$query_args['meta_query'] = array();

$query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
'key' => '_featured',
'value' => 'yes'
);
$query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();
$query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();

$r = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ($r->have_posts()) : ?>

<div id="home_featured">
<h2>Featured</h2>
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<?php while ($r->have_posts()) : $r->the_post(); global $product; ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $r->post->ID ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($r->post->post_title ? $r->post->post_title : $r->post->ID); ?>">
<?php echo $product->get_image("shop_catalog"); ?>
<h3><span><?php if ( $r->post->post_title ) echo get_the_title( $r->post->ID ); else echo $r->post->ID; ?></span></h3>
</a> <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php /*
<div id="home_bottom">
<div id="home_bottom_left" class="bottom_box">
<a class="button" href="<?=home_url()?>/product-category/rare-coins/" title="View all">View all</a>
<h2><span>Rare coin inventory</span></h2>
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 1,
'post_type'=> 'product',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => 'rare-coins'
)
)
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); $first = $post->ID; ?>
<a class="home_pic" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<a itemprop="image" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" class="zoom" rel="thumbnails" title="<?php echo get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) ) ?></a>
<?php else : ?>
<img src="<?php echo woocommerce_placeholder_img_src(); ?>" alt="Placeholder" />
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
<div class="home_bot_cont">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
</div>
<div id="home_bottom_right" class="bottom_box">
<a class="button" href="<?=home_url()?>/product-category/rare-coins/precious-metals-bullion/" title="View all">View all</a>
<h2><span>Precious Metals &amp; Bullion</span></h2>
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 1,
'post_type'=> 'product',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'exclude' => $first,
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => 'precious-metals-bullion'
)
)
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<a class="home_pic" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<a itemprop="image" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" class="zoom" rel="thumbnails" title="<?php echo get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) ) ?></a>
<?php else : ?>
<img src="<?php echo woocommerce_placeholder_img_src(); ?>" alt="Placeholder" />
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
<div class="home_bot_cont">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div> */?>

<?php // get_sidebar() ?>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: It's probably this line `<?php echo do_shortcode("[soliloquy id="79129"]"); ?>` which needs to be `<?php echo do_shortcode("[soliloquy id='79129']"); ?>`

Comment: I tried that, it gets rid of the error, but it isn't displaying the slider?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by your quotes, they are closing the string and so your have numbers that don't belong there

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[soliloquy id="79129"]"); ?>
```

you can change it to

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[soliloquy id='79129']"); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[soliloquy id=\"79129\"]"); ?>
```

Comment: I appreciate so quickly your response. I tried both of your responses and both showed no errors, but for some reason, when i go to use that shortcode, it's not calling the image slider. I have no idea what to do!! lol